# How to detect when a property of a class is changed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

When changing the frame of a `UIView`, you have two options. The first would be to pass a `CGRect` as a parameter to the `setFrame` function of a view. The other would be to set `view.frame` equal to the `CGRect`.

```
1) [view setFrame:frame];
2) view.frame = frame;
```

When using the `setFrame` function of a `UIView`, it is easy for the view to detect that it should change its frame. However, when simply changing the property (`view.frame`), **how does the view detect that its frame changed** (because the view's frame updates immediately)?

Comment: `view.frame` and `setFrame:` are the same thing. `view.frame = frame` gets translated to `[view setFrame:frame]`.

Comment: Using a property accessor on the left side of an equal sign is just dot notation for calling the setter, that is setFrame:. Your 2 "options" are identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called dot notation which came with Objective-C 2.0. They're mostly use to get and set properties.

Get a property: `view.frame`. Set a property: `view.frame = frame`.

But they're just another way or easier way ([syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)) to write: `[view frame]` and `[view setFrame:frame]`.

That's all they are, they're just translated to plain old Objective-C messages. In fact, since they're just translated to messages, try something like:

```
view.setNeedsDisplay;
```

Note that `setNeedsDisplay` is not actual property, but since it's translated to `[view setNeedsDisplay]`, it will work! By convention, dot notation is only use for getting and setting properties, so I don't suggest using something like `view.setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: +1 for recommending **against** using dot syntax for non-property message sends.

Answer (score 4):

`view.frame = frame` equals `[view setFrame:frame]`. Setting a property using dot method is same as using `setXXX:XXX`. You can put a `NSLog` in `setXXX:`, and call `obj.XXX = XXX;` And check the console to see if the `NSLog` is printed.

**Example:-**

```
view.frame = frame; //If you set frame like this then

-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    //this will be call
}
```

Comment: Exactly easiest way to know that ... Good Example +1